# POST request is not being directed to POST route in Flask

Tags: python, flask, post, routes

I am developing a web app with Flask.
I have two routes:

```py
@app.route("/<random_id>", methods = ['GET'])
def random_url(random_id):
    return "GET"

@app.route("/<random_id>", methods = ['POST'])
def random_url_post(random_id):
    return "POST"
```

When I access it with GET, I received "GET" but when I tried with POST request, it failed:

```sh
root@ubuntu:~# curl http://localhost:1337/a
GET
root@ubuntu:~# curl -xPOST http://localhost:1337/a
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: POST
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: POST
```

What can be a reason for that?

Comment: Should there be a separator between `-x` and `POST` ?

Comment: you can do it without, anyway I tried with separator and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-x` is a proxy arg. You should use `-X` in uppercase